# Jenkins low resources usage on compute engine

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am currently utilizing a VM Instance provided by Google Compute Engine, specifically the `e2-standard-4 instance (4 vCPUs and 8 GB of RAM)`, as my Jenkins controller. The pipeline I am running typically takes ~15 minutes to complete and utilizes around 90% of the available resources.

In an attempt to optimize the process, I decided to create a Jenkins agent (Spot VM) with the specifications of `e2-highcpu-16 (16 vCPUs and 16 GB of RAM)`. Surprisingly, even though the agent has more resources available, the pipeline still takes the same amount of time to run and only utilizes about 20%-30% of the vCPUs. Increasing the number of workers is not helping.

I have been unable to find a solution to this issue, so I would greatly appreciate any feedback or suggestions.

It is worth noting that when I replicate the pipeline step by step on my local PC, which has an i5-13600k processor with 14 cores, the entire process takes less than 2 minutes to complete.

Here's the htop screenhoot from Jenkins agent:
[image]

Comment: Disk performance is related to the type of persistent disk and the size. Small disks are slow. Review the disk I/O numbers to see if that is your bottleneck. A quick test is to launch another system with SSD and big disks (>500 GB).

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley I appreciate your response. I modified the disk size to 600GB (SSD persistent disk), but unfortunately, the issue persists. Despite the change, the VM continues to utilize ~30% of its resources during the pipeline execution.